# Calling paint() from another method in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, components, paint

what I am trying to achieve in Java is to be able to paint random shapes from another method without having to have those shapes already drawn from the start (user picks x, y, w, h themselves)

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Design extends JComponent {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
}

public void drawRect(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height) {
    Graphics g = null;
    g.drawRect(width, height, xPos, yPos);
}
}
```

As you can see above, I have the drawRect function coded but do not understand how to make it so when I call the drawRect() function, it gets the paint() function to draw a rectangle instead which is EXACTLY what the paint function does, inside it, you type g.drawRect() and your x,y,w,h.
The reason why I am doing this and not just straight up using paint() is because i'm trying to make a component so instead of having to type out the paint() function everytime, I just add this class to my Swing and it's done.

Hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do all paintings inside `paintComponent()` method with calling `super.paintComponent()`.

I suggest you to store all needed shapes in `List` and draw all of them in `paintComponent()`.
Instead of `drawRect` use something like `addRect` which adding new shape to your `List` and call `repaint()` method. Examine next simple example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame() {
        System.out.println("as".equalsIgnoreCase(null));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        init();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        final Design d = new Design();
        d.addRect(0,0,10,20);

        JButton b = new JButton("add");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Random r = new Random();
                int w = r.nextInt(100);
                int h = r.nextInt(100);
                d.addRect(0,0,w,h);
            }
        });
        add(d);
        add(b,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String... strings) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

    private class Design extends JComponent {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            for(Shape s : shapes){
                g2d.draw(s);
            }
        }

        public void addRect(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height) {
            shapes.add(new Rectangle(xPos,yPos,width,height));
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100,100);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thankyou everyone for the quick help! Loving SO, tried what you did here, and it actually worked exactly as expected! Just need to add more shapes now, one thing though, when I try to execute it, a rectangle is made of 4 lines, only 2 display??

Comment: You might want to consider the requirements for [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) ;)

Comment: Thankyou, figured out problem too, its just the preffered size thing, anyway I can make it infinite so you can make the rectangle any size you want??

Comment: After adding a new rectangle with any size you can recalculate prefered size for appropriate width/height.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is let go of the idea that you can control the paint process, you can't, you can respond to paint events and make requests to the `RepaintManager` that an update might be needed.

Basically, you don't call `paint` directly, paint is called in response to the `RepaintManager` wanting something painted.

Take look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

On to your code.  Don't override `paint` and certainly don't circumvent the paint process, instead, it should look something more like this...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    drawRect(g, 10, 10, 10, 10);
}

protected void drawRect(Graphics g, int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height) {
    g.drawRect(xPos, yPos, width, height);
}
```

`Graphics#drawRect` actually takes parameters `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` in that order...

> The reason why I am doing this and not just straight up using paint() is because i'm trying to make a component so instead of having to type out the paint() function every time

Doesn't make sense, that's the point of having the `paint` methods, so you can customise the way a component is paint, make lots of instances of it and add it your GUI...this is how all the Swing controls work...

Also, you might find [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) of interest

**Updated based on comments**

So, you want a method that some other object can call and it will enable them to add a "rectangle" to the the existing object/component...

Start by defining an instance variable of `Rectangle`

```
private Rectangle rectangle;
```

In your `paintComponent`, check to see if `rectangle` is `null` or not and if it's not, paint it...

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (rectangle != null)  {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.draw(rectangle);
    }
}
```

Now, update your `drawRect` method to create an instance `Rectangle` and request that the component be repainted

```
public void drawRect(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height) {
    rectangle = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height);
    repaint();
}
```

For example...

```
public class Design extends JComponent {

    private Rectangle rectangle;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (rectangle != null)  {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2d.draw(rectangle);
        }
    }

    public void drawRect(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height) {
        rectangle = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to support having multiple rectangles, you could simply use a `List` and add as many instances `Rectangle` as you want, iterating over the `List` in the `paintComponent` method

Comment: Thanks for the input, as in the paintComponent() method you wrote drawRect(g, 10, 10, 10, 10); but what I'm trying to do is be able to execute that from another class, all thats doing is the second I call the method is it's going to force itself to draw a rectangle, I want control over doing it as I wish almost like an instance of the class. I'm not being forced that way to draw a rectangle, I do it as I please.

Comment: Yes thankyou, just as the other person, that is perfect. Thankyou again for your quick support, if I could also choose another, well consider yourself correct. Thanks.